# Accessing active storage has_many_attached through child of parent

Tags: rails-activestorage

I am trying to access active storage attachments of a parent record in the Rails view.

```
# product.rb model
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants, inverse_of: :product
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
end

# variant.rb model
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

#variants/index.html.erb
<% @variants.each do |variant| %>
  <%= variant.product.images.first.service_url %>
<% end %>
```

The index.html does not show any URL even though I have confirmed the product does indeed have an attachment which is in the S3 bucket. When I try to access the image url in the terminal directly through the parent product i.e. Product.find(21).images.first.service_url, it DOES produce the URL successfully. For some reason when I do it through the child variant in the view, it shows up as nil.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?